# Hard English Texts or Texts with hard English?

Tags: phrase-request

What is the best thing to call hard English texts? I mean texts that are hard language-wise, and for example are very hard for non-native readers.

- Texts with hard English?
- Texts with a hard English?
- Texts with heavy English?
- Tough English texts?

Comment: Difficult English texts?

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest **Challenging English texts** or **advanced English texts**

As a native English speaker, if I were to see something like this on a foreign language learning site, I would expect to see them described in English as:

- Advanced English texts
- Challenging English texts
- Difficult English texts
- Hard English texts

Which one you want will depend on context.

**Advanced** does not literally mean "hard," but it indicates that they are for use by advanced students of the language only, and the implication is that the language is difficult.

**Challenging** indicates that they will be a challenge for the reader, but also has a positive implication: a challenge can be a good thing; a difficulty or hardship is a bad thing.

Answer (score -1):

*Formal language*  is an expression used to describe a text, speech... that is elegantly composed using pertinent words. It is usually used for literature and poetry.

The contemporary definitions for *formal language* from [the dictionary reference](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/formal+language) is:

> any language that is ceremonial or using a "high" register or hard words, such as a sermon, lecture, or poetry

So, it is indeed hard language-wise, and very hard for non-native readers.

In your case you would say: *A formal English text*.

Comment: Writings in say Scouse and Geordie are rarely labelled 'high register'. Or 'easy'.

Comment: You haven't addressed the issue, it's not whether English can be *hard* to grasp or understand, but how to express that concept. The OP has supplied several options, which you ignored.

Comment: @Mari-Lou A The OP question is 'What is the best thing to call hard English texts?'. IMO this expression is better than the answers the OP provided. Providing a different answer implicitly implies this, doesn't it?

Comment: You've now supplied a more complete answer in your edit.

Comment: Like @Edwin implied, there are many cases where high register and erudite words do not necessarily have anything to do with how difficult a text is to a non-native reader. As an example, I’m currently re-reading _At Swim, Two Boys_ by Jamie O’Neill; the book starts: _“There goes Mr. Mack, cock of the town. One foot up, the other foot down. The hell of a gent. With a tip of his hat here and a top of the morn there, tip-top, everything’s dandy. He’d bare his head to a lamppost.”_ That’s not high register or formal language, but a non-native speaker would probably find the book immensely hard.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Would you describe the text you cited as ' texts that are hard language-wise'?

Comment: Certainly I would. In particular, I'd describe it (as the asker did) as “very hard for non-native readers”.

Comment: For me, it is indeed 'very hard for non-native readers' but not 'hard language-wise'.

Comment: The language used makes it hard to understand. If 'hard language' is a collocation-grading-to-compound-noun, I'd say it usually invokes the 'stern words' or 'harsh language' sense. 'Hard English' virtually forces a different meaning on 'hard'.